# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer similarity_model: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, similarity

I am creating model using tensorflow_similarity.
The error raised when the first epoch finish.

`INPUT_SHAPE = (224,224,3)`

My model
(Same as example repo https://github.com/tensorflow/similarity/blob/master/examples/supervised_hello_world.ipynb)

```
def create_model():
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
x = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 7, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 7, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

outputs = MetricEmbedding(64)(x)
return SimilarityModel(inputs, outputs)
```

I have tried with different model by the api also

```
model = EfficientNetSim(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,embedding_size = 128,variant = "B0",augmentation = False,weights = None)
```

The error also raise the same as before.

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer similarity_model: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 3)
```

Comment: Try shape = (224,224,3,) maybe you're missing the batch dimension, even if I think that's handled by the fit

Comment: Ye It's handled by the fit. Still raise the error.
Thanks @PaoloJ42

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure I got it: it's expecting a pure input tensor, try inputs = keras.Input(shape = INPUT_SHAPE) and put the full model AFTER the preprocessing (i.e. an input layer)

Comment: Still raise the error. The tensorflow_similarity api is so new . I'm trying to dig in.
Really appreciate your help @PaoloJ426

Comment: @PaoloJ426 I solved the error.
It was the validation_data that in the fit.
The samplers in tensorflow_similarity generate new batches that was not equal to the validation_data.
Solved by give validation data in ( x_val , y_val ) or make equal to samplers's batch

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error. It was the validation_data that in the fit. The samplers in tensorflow_similarity generate new batches that was not equal to the validation_data. Solved by give validation data in ( x_val , y_val ) or make equal to samplers's batch.